# drawing image relative to screen size android

Tags: android, position, screen-size

I am making a game and I want the player to start off with a 'X' position half way through the screen, and a 'Y' position where the bottom of the player is 5 pixels above the bottom of the screen.I tried using display and display metrics to get the screen size and set the x and y positions relative to that, but it doesn't seen to work.The image doesn't draw on the screen at all. I just get a blank screen. It works though, if I give constant coordinates(ex.100,50). This is how I am trying to achieve this now :

`x = (displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2);
 y = displayMetrics.heightPixels - (height + 5);`

This is how the custom view is drawing it to the screen:

`canvas.drawBitmap(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), null);`

Custom view class -

```
public class GameGraphics extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private Thread gameGraphics;
private GameCore gameCore;
private Player player;

public GameGraphics(Context context, GameCore gameCore) {
    super(context);
    this.gameCore = gameCore;
    this.player = gameCore.getPlayer();
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    gameGraphics = new Thread(this);
    gameGraphics.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {     
    while(gameCore.isRunning() == true){
        if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), null);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

}
```

Player Class -

```
public Player(GameCore gameCore, Context context) {
    this.gameCore = gameCore;
    this.context = context;
    displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    gameCore.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    /* INITIALIZE HEIGHT AND WIDTH VARIABLES */
    height = 72;
    width = 72;
    x = (displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2); 
    y = displayMetrics.heightPixels - (height + 5);
    xChange = 0;
    /* INITIALIZE IMAGE */
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}
```

***I'm using the default ic_launcher for testing ****

Comment: can you post more code of your custom view class?